# How to copy named range from one workbook to another workbook in specific cell?

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my original code. I am trying to change my code so that add/delete new columns/rows won't affect the new created workbook. I decided to use the name range to avoid the code crushed. (I know how to create the new range in the Name manager) Anyone knows how to adjust the code?

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim myWs As Worksheet
Set myWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MASTER")
Set Rng1 = myWs.Range("A1:AJ4")
Set Rng2 = myWs.Range("A85:AJ104")
Application.Workbooks.Add
Set WS = Application.ActiveSheet
Rng1.Copy Destination:=WS.Range("A1:AJ4")
Rng2.Copy Destination:=WS.Range("A5:AJ50")
```

Comment: I don't see any columns being added or deleted or any Named Ranges being used. Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54009792/edit) to clarify what the problem is?

Comment: I am trying to change my code so that add/delete new columns/rows won't affect my new created workbook.

Comment: They shouldn't, if you assign the ranges correctly...right?  I'm not sure what the question is, can you please clarify?

Comment: okay, if I insert the value into A1 in the original workbook, then the value in new workbook will move to right, how can I lock it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to dim each workbook and worksheet you will be using.

```
Dim wb1 as Workbook, wb2 as Workbook, ws1 as Worksheet, ws2 as Worksheet
Dim xrow as long, arrData() as variant

Set wb1 = Workbooks("Book1")
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set wb2 = Workbooks("Book2")
Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet2")
```

Note that this only works if you have both workbooks open.

Also I would recommend copying the data from each cell to an array, instead of copying a range.  I get less errors this way.

```
ApplicationScreenUpdating = False

ws1.Activate

'where n is the number of rows you want to copy
for x = 1 To n
arrData[x - 1] = ws1.Cells(x, 1).value
next x

ws2.Activate

for i = 1 to n
ws2.Cells(i, 1).value = arrData[i - 1]
next i

ApplicationScreenUpdating = True
```